# Windows 7 app launcher

Tags: windows-7, launcher

Is there any App Launcher for Windows 7 in which you can place shortcuts of your favorite applications? I've got a lot of software which I would like to categorize and place them where I can easily start them.

[Pokki](http://www.pokki.com/) is very beautiful and very handy but it's super slow and uses extensive resources.

[image: Pokki]

[RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/) is also very useful but it's not being updated any longer and it only appears as either vertical or horizontal bar.

Comment: RocketDock is really solid, despite the fact that it doesn't get updated anymore.

Comment: Related: [Are there any windows taskbar App Lancher like Chrome App Launcher?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/are-there-any-windows-taskbar-app-lancher-like-chrome-app-launcher)

Answer (score 4):

I vote for [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/). You can configure which folders it has to search – so besides your applications it can offer you your favorite PDF's, Excel sheets, e-books etc.

It also can be configured to search inside words, so you can find your **YearReport.doc** by typing `rep` .

Answer (score 3):

I found [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) to be quite useful, although it doesn't have the fancy interface Pokki has.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/) for a couple of years.  And by installing the [Stacks Docklet](http://rocketdock.com/addon/docklets/1791) you have the option of setting up folders of icons grouped by type.

In the [Stacks Docklet](http://rocketdock.com/addon/docklets/1791) you have the option of having these folders opening up in a GRID "underneath" the [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/).

** Please Note ** There is a "difficulty" if you are using the 64-bit version of Windows 7, but there is a [very easy workaround](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/217403-tut-create-proper-64-bit-apps-shortcuts-stack-docklet.html).

Even though it's no longer being "supported" by it's author, it has never given me any problems and as indicated above, when a "new" problem was found upon the release of Windows 7 64-bit OS, someone out there sat down and figured out what the problem was and a way around it.

Still the best way to go!