# Are there any windows taskbar App Lancher like Chrome App Launcher?

Tags: windows-8, launcher

Google 's [Chrome App Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher) is very nice. Are there any way I can launch any apps/programs on my windows 8 like this?
[image]

Comment: related: [Windows 7 app launcher](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/windows-7-app-launcher)